# Mapping Ctrl+w to Alt+w sends both Ctrl+Alt+w

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using Autohotkey to map Ctrl+w to Alt+w for Cloud9 to close inner tabs with Ctrl+w like usual instead of their Alt+w. I tried to use the following simple mapping

```
^w::!w
```

But it sends Ctrl+Alt+w with closes all tabs except current tab which wasn't what I wanted.

How can I tell autohotkey to not actually send the Ctrl key that I press for this hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
Ctrl & w::Send !w
```

[AutoHotKey has special handling](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) for remapping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key:

> When the source key is LCtrl and the destination key is an Alt key,
>   the line Send {Blind}{LAlt DownTemp} is replaced by Send {Blind}{LCtrl
>   Up}{LAlt DownTemp}. The same is true if the source is RCtrl, except
>   that {RCtrl up} is used.

This special handling is specifically designed to prevent the behavior you observed. If you think about a simpler remapping like `p::v`, you'd probably want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to be treated like `^v` so that you can paste with your <kbd>P</kbd>. In general, AutoHotKey tries to allow modifying keys to do their thing while triggering a hotkey.

Comment: Works! But any reason I should do both `LCtrl` and `RCtrl` instead of `Ctrl & w::Send !w`? it works too.

Comment: Nope. I just assumed from the quoted text that I needed to use `LCtrl` instead of `Ctrl`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this :

> ^x::^c    Makes Control-X produce Control-C. It also makes Control-Alt-X
>   produce Control-Alt-C, etc.

It is taken from the AutoHotkey Help Pages.

What  have you done is : Control-W produces Alt-W.

You said you wanted to use Ctrl+W to close tabs.

If Ctrl-W produces Cltrl-Alt-W because it produces Alt-W and Cltr-W at same time, it means that the application has time to catch the internal signal.

It might be because the application is looking for the BIOS keys or either that that auto-hotkey doesn't react fast enough.

I remember that there's was an option to put a autohotkey to sleep for x-time or make send more signals at the same time.

Sending more signals at the same time will prevent the Key from the Bios to reach the application. AutoHotkey will always translate the stroke so the application will *read* the right keys/AutoHotkey signals only.

I hope my long explanation helped you.